# Prevent commits in a local branch

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

In my local git tree I pull commits from the "master" branch in the repository, but all development is done in a different branch, and pushed in a different branch too.

I would like to avoid mistakes and prevent accidental commits in my local "master" branch, and allow only pull requests (then I'd rebase the developement branch to the updated master). Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a [**pre-commit hook**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

For example, place the following script as `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) = "master" ; then 
  echo "Cannot commit on master"
  exit 1
fi
```

And set it as executable

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I needed. Just to be sure, that wouldn't interfere with "git pull", right? I ask because I cannot test it until there's some update in the server.

Comment: No. it should be fine, it will only affect trying to commit to master.

Comment: @Jellby: in order to test : `git clone /my/local/project project-test; cd project-test` Then use `project-test` with `project` as remote, and test your hook with `testBracnh` instead of `master`

Comment: it is not clear, whether `test` should be substituted with something? or it is a part of the script?

Comment: No, test is the unix `test` command and should be left as is.